# Why does Intl.DateTimeFormat return different months in Safari depending on year?

Tags: date, safari

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {'month': 'short'}).format(new Date(2007, 3));
> "Apr"

new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {'month': 'short'}).format(new Date(2006, 3));
> "Mar"

new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {'month': 'short'}).format(new Date(2007, 10));
> "Nov"

new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {'month': 'short'}).format(new Date(2006, 10));
> "Oct"
```

Safari `Version 11.1 (13605.1.33.1.4)`

In Chrome it returns what I expect (Apr, Apr, Nov, Nov).

Comment: It may have to do with DST.  What time zone are you in?

Comment: America/Los_Angeles. `new Date()` returns `Thu May 31 2018 17:46:35 GMT-0700 (PDT)`

Comment: Ah interesting, 2007 was the year that Daylight Saving Time in the USA was changed from the first Sunday of April to the second Sunday of March (and likewise from the last Sunday of October to the first Sunday of November). https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/STATUTE-119/pdf/STATUTE-119-Pg594.pdf#page=22